# Javaで500エラーになる原因と調査方法

Tags: java, apache, eclipse, spring, tomcat

EclipseでJavaプロジェクトをサーバーでデバックすると500エラーになります。

tomcatの設定かDB周りのエラーなのだと思いますが、原因がわかりません。

環境：
Java8
tomcat v8.5

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'XXXXXX': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'XXXXXX'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'XXXXXX': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'XXXXXXDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'XXXXXX': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:592)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:624)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1673)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

（'XXXXXX'は固有のコントローラー名のため伏せてます）

1行目のエラーはコントローラークラスのbeanを作成できないと言われているので、
springのエラーなのかとも思いますが
マーケットプレイスでspringは追加済みです。

確認すべき箇所がどこなのか検討がつきません。。。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Eclipseのバージョンを変更したらなぜか解決しました。
自己解決しましたので、クローズします。